# How to add Google Play Games sign up script in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I want to know how to implement google Play games services to any Unity app. I was just going through some tutorials but it's not working, I don't know where I am doing it wrong... maybe there's some mistake I am making in my script but I couldn't find it. Can anyone tell me what should I do to make it work?

I have an empty game object in my scene and I have attached the script to it. I just want the sign in using Google prompt window to be launched when I launch the app and if user has already logged in it should not prompt the log in window.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using GooglePlayGames;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;

public class PlayGameServices : MonoBehaviour {
public void Start () {

    //Google Play Services
    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();

    PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;

    pSLogin ();

}

public void Update () {

}

//Google Play Services for login
public void pSLogin()
{
    Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) =>
        {
            if(success)
            {
                Debug.Log("You've successfully logged in");                 
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Log in Unsuccessful");
            }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Google Play Games plugin for Unity® is an open-source project whose goal is to provide a plugin that allows game developers to integrate with the Google Play Games API from a game written in Unity®. However, this project is not in any way endorsed or supervised by Unity Technologies. Use instruction from [here](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity)